# How to match to capture group 1 with regex

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to capture the date from the following string:

`<span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span><span class="ratingDate relativeDate" title="November 9, 2017">Reviewed 2 days ago </span><a class="viaMobile" href="/apps" target="_blank" onclick="ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(24487)"><span class="ui_icon mobile-phone"></span>via mobile </a>`

To do this I'm using the regex:`title="(*?)"`
Which returns Match (group 0): `title="November 9, 2017"` Group 1: `November 9, 2017`

I need my match returned by regex to be just the date, what is currently group 1. Is there a simple way to do this? I am new to regex but I could find direction on this online.

Note: I'm not writing regex for the structure of a date because some strings have multiple dates and I only want the date in title. Thanks!

Comment: Which language are you using? That will determine how you get the capture group.

Comment: Guess: you're using Java, then see [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)): "...Group zero denotes the entire pattern..."

Comment: I'm using Python. I was wondering if it was possible to do this in the Regex itself. Does the implementation require whatever parent language relevant to be used?

Comment: `\1` should have the first capture group in it. The regex also is missing a `.`, probably want `title="(.*?)"`.

Comment: You are not trying to summon Cthulhu by parsing html with regex, are you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead / lookbehind instead of capture groups

```
(?<=title=\").+?(?=")
```

This will ensure it starts with title, without actually selecting it

Comment: In Node 14.8.2 w/ eslint for me, I get a complaint about the escape character (`no-useless-escape` rule)....`(?<=title=").+?(?=")` should also work... does in my own case anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
title="\K.*?(?=")
```

This will look for the value between `title="` and `"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = """
  <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span><span class="ratingDate relativeDate" title="November 9, 2017">Reviewed 2 days ago </span><a class="viaMobile" href="/apps" target="_blank" onclick="ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(24487)"><span class="ui_icon mobile-phone"></span>via mobile </a>
  """
date = re.findall('title="(.*?)"', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'November 9, 2017'
```